# R: How to change single df-value based on other column value?

Tags: r

I want to change a single value in a df-column, according to a character in another column. Here a small example (I want to change the code [,2] of the Seychelles):

```
cntry <- c("Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles", "Sierra Leone")
code <- c(194,195,272,1351,197)
CNTRYcode <- data.frame(cntry,code)
```

I would use indexing:

```
CNTRYcode[4,2] <- 196
```

The problem is that the entrances in my df maybe change. So, how to change the code using the cntry-column? Thanks

Comment: You can do `CNTRYcode$code[CNTRYcode$cntry == "Seychelles"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing `data.frame` subsetting, you don't have to hard-code numbers - you can call function that will return expected number. Like `match()`.

This way will modify `data.frame` directly:

```
CNTRYcode[match("Seychelles", CNTRYcode$cntry), 2]
CNTRYcode[match("Seychelles", CNTRYcode$cntry), "code"]
```

The second example refers to column by name, so it will work even if you decide to put third column between `cntry` and `code`.

Another approach takes advantage of the fact that instead of using numerical indices, you can submit vector of logical values:

```
CNTRYcode$cntry == "Seychelles"
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
CNTRYcode[CNTRYcode$cntry == "Seychelles", "code"]
```

This is especially useful if you want more refined search criteria - you can use `&` for conjunction (AND) and `|` for alternative (OR). Some other programming languages might get you used to double operands (`&&` and `||`) but in R, they will reduce vector into single value - and this is not what you want in this case.

You can also find position looked-up value in vector of keys and modify whatever happens to be on the same position in vector of values that you want to change:

```
CNTRYcode$code[CNTRYcode$cntry == "Seychelles"]
```